# Need to combine counts from multiple tables with common column names

Tags: sql, count

I have 2 tables that I'm trying to get counts from depending on the date. In other words, all records in the table from 1/1/2018 would be counted and returned to the "Count" column.

My query works, but what I end up with are 2 dates, 1 from each table. What I want to end up with is 1 date with the summed counts from both tables.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101) AS DWSTOREDATETIME
, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM [dwdata].[dbo].SO00
  WHERE DWSTOREDATETIME > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND DWSTOREDATETIME < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101)

  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101) AS DWSTOREDATETIME
, COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM [dwdata].[dbo].NO00
  WHERE DWSTOREDATETIME > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND DWSTOREDATETIME < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101)
```

So, instead of a record showing 1/1/2018 Count:1 
and another record showing 1/1/2018 Count:2

I'd have a single record showing 1/1/2018 Count:3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must get the `SUM` of the corresponding dates of the `UNION` of the 2 subqueries:

```
SELECT t.DWSTOREDATETIME, SUM(t.Count) AS Count
FROM(
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101) AS DWSTOREDATETIME
  , COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM [dwdata].[dbo].SO00
  WHERE DWSTOREDATETIME > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND DWSTOREDATETIME < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101) AS DWSTOREDATETIME
  , COUNT(*) AS Count
  FROM [dwdata].[dbo].NO00
  WHERE DWSTOREDATETIME > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND DWSTOREDATETIME < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101)
) AS t
GROUP BY t.DWSTOREDATETIME
```

Answer (score 1):

An option could be a union and a temp table. The union basically puts both sets of data into the same data set, and then you can count them in a single table with the temp table.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101) AS DWSTOREDATETIME
into #table
  FROM [dwdata].[dbo].SO00
  WHERE DWSTOREDATETIME > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND DWSTOREDATETIME < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101)

Union All

  SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101) AS DWSTOREDATETIME

  FROM [dwdata].[dbo].NO00
  WHERE DWSTOREDATETIME > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND DWSTOREDATETIME < '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
  GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar(10),DWSTOREDATETIME, 101)

select DWSTOREDATETIME, COUNT(*)
FROM #table
```